# Split long legend of Grob object in 2 columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, grid, gridextra

So i have a grob object of a heatmap where my actual groups (conditions) are too many (49) and as a result it overflows the plot. My question is how can I split the legend grob with the conditions (condition1-10) to more than one column (e.g. 2 of 10 on the example or 2 of 25 in the original one) so that it fits the plot.

Thanks!

```
data <- replicate(20, rnorm(50))
rownames(data) <- paste("Gene", c(1:nrow(data)))
colnames(data) <- paste("Sample", c(1:ncol(data)))

metadata <- data.frame(
c(rep("cond1", ncol(data)/10), rep("cond2", ncol(data)/10), rep("cond3", ncol(data)/10),
rep("cond4", ncol(data)/10), rep("cond5", ncol(data)/10), rep("cond6", ncol(data)/10),
rep("cond7", ncol(data)/10), rep("cond8", ncol(data)/10), rep("cond9", ncol(data)/10),
rep("cond10", ncol(data)/10)), row.names=colnames(data))

colnames(metadata) <- c("condition")

require(pheatmap)
out <- pheatmap(data, 
            show_rownames=F, cluster_cols=T, cluster_rows=T, scale="row",
            cex=1, clustering_distance_rows="euclidean", cex=1,
            clustering_distance_cols="euclidean", clustering_method="complete", border_color=FALSE,
            annotation_col=metadata,
            annotation_row=metadata_gene)

grid::grid.draw(out$gtable)
```

[image]